# Send Mail on successful registration

Tags: php, html, sql, http-headers

I'm trying to code a script in order to mail the user upon his/her successful registration using PHP.
The user gets registered successful in the database, though the email is not being sent.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
function send_mail($id,$name,$email,$password)
{   
    $from='Admin <admin@mydomain.com>';
    $headers = '';
    $headers .= "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-to: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Message-ID: <" . md5(uniqid(time())) . "@" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ">\n";
    $headers .= "Date: " . date('r', time()) . "\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

}
$subject = "Welcome!";
$message = "
<p></p><br>
Hi ".$name."<br>
Thank you for registering for the event.<br><br>
Your ID is ".$id."<br>
Login using your email id : ".$email." and,<br>
your password : ".$password."<br><br>
";


mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

In my `register.php` script I've included:

```
send_mail($u_id,$u_name,$_POST['email'],$password)
```

The parameters of the function are `id` (INT), `name` (VARCHAR), `email` (VARCHAR) & `password` (VARCHAR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your mail() function is outside of send_mail() function.

Change it into,

```
function send_mail($id,$name,$email,$password)
{   
    $from='Admin <admin@mydomain.com>';
    $headers = '';
    $headers .= "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-to: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Message-ID: <" . md5(uniqid(time())) . "@" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ">\n";
    $headers .= "Date: " . date('r', time()) . "\n";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

    $subject = "Welcome!";
    $message = "
    <p></p><br>
    Hi ".$name."<br>
   Thank you for registering for the event.<br><br>
   Your ID is ".$id."<br>
   Login using your email id : ".$email." and,<br>
   your password : ".$password."<br><br>";


  mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the function loop after mail function instead of closing before sub